# How to add class to all elements inside div?

Tags: css

I have 100 buttons inside a div:

```
<div class="button_group">
  <button> ... </button>
  <button> ... </button>
  <button> ... </button>
  ...
</div>
```

I want to style all buttons in the bootstrap style. So, I need to change everywhere < button > to < button class="btn" >. I want to do it without actually adding class="btn" 100 times for each < button > element. So, I need some CSS rule that says that all buttons inside the div are of class "btn". So, I need something like this:

```
.button_group button {
  ... add class="btn" to all elements ...
}
```

Is it possible at all? What is the correct syntax?

Thank you!!

Comment: You would use css to styles all the buttons, but for adding a class you would typically use javascript

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="button_group">
  <button> ... </button>
  <button> ... </button>
  <button> ... </button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button_group > button {width: 100px; height: 50px;}
```

And the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/049Lj4LL/4/

There is no need to ad `class="btn"` to every button if they are the same, just add a class to the parent `div` like you have `class="button_group"` to be able to identify that specific group of buttons. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/049Lj4LL/6/ and like this https://jsfiddle.net/049Lj4LL/7/

Comment: thank you for your answer, but these are examples of how to style the buttons. The bootstrap class "btn" already has its styling and I just want to re-use it.

Comment: You never specified bootstrap in your question, when using SO for questions it is best to put all relevant conditions in your question. Since you are using bootstrap and you "need" `btn` inserted into so many fields, you will need to use something like javascript, you cannot do that in pure css.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a jquery-like library, you would add a class `btn` to all the `<button>` elements like that :

```
$('div.button_group button').addClass('btn');
```

Edit: In case you are using the sass or less version of bootstrap, which I encourage you, you can try to extend the `btn` bootstrap class. Contrary to the javascript solution mentioned above, that won't *add the class* `btn` to the elements, but they will inherit the styles of the `btn` class. Here is the sass solution :

```
.button_group {
    button {
        @extend .btn;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would never use jQuery to achieve what OP wants. He just wants to target specific buttons which is easily done with CSS. I think his qustion should have been: how do I target.....

Comment: You are here making assumptions that could be clarifed with op in comments. The OP question is *how to add a class to all elements?* so I answered to that. OP is using bootstrap and seems he want to reuse the *btn* class.

Comment: I will complete the answer with another possibility to 'apply' the *btn* class of bootstrap but without js.

Comment: Yep, I know I am making an assumption. Your answer is perfectly fine. No worries dude.

Comment: thank you for the answers. The example with @extend does not work for me, maybe because I don't use sass or less versions of bootstrap. The example with jQuery does not work as well, I have the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of null. This might be because I'm probably using the jQuery function calls not correctly in my template. I will think about some workaround, thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Yep, the `@extend` solution will work only if you build bootstrap css from the [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) version. As for your problem using the jQuery solution, I can't tell what's wrong without seeing more, but see if this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shs8a97q/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript.
In JS, you can use the `childNodes` property of the `div` element, that you can access using `document.getElementByClassName`. In the array `document.getElementByClassName("button_group").childNodes` are initialized all the button tags written in the div. Set the class name with `.className`. Add the JS code to your HTML with the `script` tag:

```
<script>
    for(let i=0; i<document.getElementByClassName("button_group").childNodes.length; i++){
       document.getElementByClassName("button_group").childNodes[i].className="theClassNameYouDesire";
    }
</script>
```